# xmlbeans could not locate schema resource when repacking xml beans jar into my own jar

Tags: java, apache-poi, xmlbeans

I am writing an application that needs to be contained in a jar.

The program needs to validate and grab data from an excel spreadsheet. Therefore I am using the Apache POI libraries which are dependent on xmlbeans jar.

My problem is that when I include the xmlbeans jar in my jar using ant

```
<jar 
...
<zipfileset src="${xmlbeans.jar}" includes="**/*" />
```

Build and then run the jar, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeLoaderException: XML-BEANS compiled schema: Could not locate compiled schema resource schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/system/sE130CAA0A01A7CDE5A2B4FEB8B311707/index.xsb (schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sE130CAA0A01A7CDE5A2B4FEB8B311707.index) - code 0
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl$XsbReader.<init>(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:1519)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl.initFromHeader(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:273)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl.<init>(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:185)
```

When unit testing with testng this works fine.  So the problem obviously lies with incorporating the xmlbeans jar into my jar.  Is it possible to do this?  POI libraries are dependent on it.

I have uncompressed my jar, and indeed the resource is missing.

I am using the correct version of xmlbeans for the poi libraries I am using.

Here are the libraries I am using:

poi-3.7.jar
poi-ooxml-3.7-beta3.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7-beta3.jar

and the following version of xmlbeans:

xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar

Many thanks

Comment: It should be easy to look in your jar to see if "schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/system/sE130CAA0A01A7CDE5A2B4FEB8B311707/index.xsb" is in there.  That would tell you a lot about what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  I have looked and it is not there. "schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/system/sE130CAA0A01A7CDE5A2B4FEB8B311707" directory is present, but it doesn't contain index.xsb.  It appears that this directory is created when ant packs it into the jar, but is not including the expected index.xsb file.  This directory does not exist in the original source xmlbeans jar

Comment: I think those .xsb files are part of the compiled schema, check how you are including the generated files, probably in poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7-beta3.jar

Comment: yes, that was it.  thanks.  was only including the class files from poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7-beta3.jar